# Error enabling MongoDB module

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to use MongoDB with drupal 7 site. The database is hosted remotely on mongolab.com.

I have installed the MongoDB Driver on my dedicated server and it added `extension = "mongo.so"` to my `php.ini` automatically.

Now, when I try to enable MongoDB module, it gives me this error:

> Mongodb requires the PHP MongoDB extension to be installed. (Currently using Mongodb Not found)

Any ideas why?

Comment: When you use `phpinfo()` in a script do you see a `mongodb` section?

Comment: No. There is no mongodb section.

Comment: check your php.ini file. and make the mongo db enable.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha, could you please tell me how to `make the mongo db enable` ?! (in code)

Comment: I am guessing that either your php.ini is cached by APC or FCGI modules or you are running this in console and there are two php.ini files or it didn't actually add it to the php.ini and just said it did like the big fat liar it is

Comment: Oh wait, just to check; did you check for a `mongo` section as well? I misspelt how the driver calls itself in the configuration, it calls itself `mongo` not `mongodb`

Comment: No. There is no mongo section neither.

Comment: Ok yea take my comment just before, check all your php.inis and if you are running APC or a fcgi module restart it, if you installed through pecl it will not add the line to your php.ini automatically even if it says it did.

Comment: @Sammaye; I installed it via PECL and the php.ini already has `extension = "mongo.so"`

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/1730/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-php/ check this link.

Comment: How to point `extension_dir variable` to the location of `mongo.so` ?!

Comment: It should already, you shouldnt need to change the `extension_dir` config variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292362/how-to-install-php-mongo-on-centos-5-3 also check this URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In your phpinfo() screen, make sure the Configuration file Path and Loaded Configuration File match the PHP file you are editing. If not, then find the correct php.ini and add the mongo.so extension.

2) In your phpinfo() screen, look at the `extension_dir` value and confirm that `mongo.so` exists in that directory. If not, find the mongo.so file and copy it to this directory.

3) Restart your web server.

4) If it's still not working, take a look at the web server & php logs for clues as to why the extension might not be loading.

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall, nothing was helping me. I realized that php.ini file was not reflecting changes so I found out that I should restart php-fpm like `sudo systemctl restart php-7.3-fpm` that was it!